# Notation for set union that results in a multiset

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, multisets

Is there a notation that replaces the "union" operator $A\cup B$ and emphasizes that the outcome should be considered a multi-set rather than a set? For example, if $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and $B =\{3,4,5\}$, then:

$$A ? B = \{1,2,3,3,4,5\}$$

since the $3$ is counted twice. What operator can I used instead of the "$?$"?

Comment: Maybe disjoint union is what you are looking for. See the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is sometimes called “additive union”.  (For example, see Blizard, W. [“Multiset Theory”](https://doi.org/10.1305/ndjfl/1093634995).)  There is no truly standard notation for multiset operations, but $$A\uplus B$$ is often used for additive union.  The MathJax code is `\uplus`.

Comment: Just to add, there are various terms used for this multiset operation, including 'addition', 'sum' and 'merge'. [See Definition 7, Page 78 of Singh, D. et.al. (2007). An overview of the applications of multisets. Novi Sad J. Math. 37(2), 73-92]. I have a preference for merge. Not only does merge have a natural alignment to essence of this operation, it also provides multisets with a uniquely different term from classical sets.

Comment: If I need to additively union together a large/varying/arbitrary amount of these, would `\biguplus` be an appropriate notation?$$\biguplus\left\{\left[1, 1\right], \left[1, 2\right], \left[2, 3\right]\right\} = \left[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3\right]$$

Comment: Any notation is appropriate as long as you state clearly what it means.  For something like this, don't assume that anyone will understand without an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For multiset union (and intersection, etc) just use the usual symbols. Just make clear you are talking multisets, not sets.

Comment: Even in the context of multisets, the writer will want to make clear that $\cup$ represents additive union $A+B$ rather than max-union $\max(A, B)$.